# How to add JavaScript code to a webform?

Tags: 7, webforms, javascript

I want to add JavaScript code to a webform. For example, to add things like onclick, onchange, mouseover function to webform's textbox, textarea, select, email, etc.

How do I do so?

Answer (score 6):

The recommended way to add a JS to any form in Drupal is using [#attached](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) to the `$form` element.

In order to add the JS to a webform, you would have to implement `hook_form_alter` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`, and add the `#attached`

```
function MODULE_form_webform_client_form_3_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE') . '/MODULE.js',
  );
}
```

Then create the MODULE.js file inside the module directory, and write your JS there.

Refer to [The Drupal JavaScript API](https://www.drupal.org/node/304258), to see how to work with JS in Drupal way.

Comment: Thank for reply. I wonder is there any basic tutorial for me to learn this?

Comment: You could also add a library : $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'xxxx/xxx';. 
Do not forget to create a library using the yourmodule.libraries.yml file of your custom module.

Answer (score -1):

To load a script on a specific form , follow the following steps:

1. Copy webform-form.tpl.php to your sub-theme's root directory.
2. Rename it webform-form-NID.tpl.php, where NID is the node ID of your
   webform.
3. Add the following code in above created theme file:

> drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() .'/scripts/SCRIPT_NAME.js');